# I have a process writing to a terminal. I can't find what process it is. It survives reboot

Tags: command-line, scripts, reboot, process

A small shell script writes to a terminal, in while-loop, with `echo`.

If I close the terminal, it re-attaches to the new terminal I start - usually `/dev/pts/0` but it has also attached to `/dev/pts/10`.

It survives re-boot. I can't find what process it is:

```
ps -elf | awk '{if ($5 == 1){print $4" "$5" "$15}}'
```

shows no shells running apart from the terminal I am on, and the `pts` it is writing to. If I kill those, and start again, it continues to write, but I see no shell.

The script sleeps for a second. I've tried looking for `sleep` in `ps`, but it never seems to appear.

How can I find and kill it? I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 btw.

Comment: Do you know what it is? How do you know it's a "small shell script"?

Comment: Can you provide  any other details?

Comment: I wrote the script - it's a for loop, with a sleep 1, and a write to the terminal. I don't have the exact script, it's not in my history. I was trying to test something else, and got stuck with it as an orphan process.

Comment: AFAIK processes don't survive boot - so it's most likely something that's being run from one of your shell initialization scripts (`~/.bashrc`, ~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` etc.)

Comment: Yes, it must be stored somewhere and invoked during boot.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. It is stored some where - not any of the start-up scripts. It doesn't have a name, it is just a few lines of script written in a shell. Something is resurrecting it. It'd be good to know what it is, and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's writing to the terminal it must have (probably has) a handle to the terminal. In that case

```
lsof `tty`
```

from the terminal it's writing to should list it, giving you the pid.

(Or substitute the actual terminal e.g. `lsof /dev/pts/0`.)

Comment: Thank you, a good approach. Unfortunately, it is spawning too quickly to do much about it. lsof gives the PID, but, before there's a chance to kill it, it's respawned with a new one.

Comment: Can you get the parent pid?

Comment: Yes. Again, unfortunately, it only sees the shell itself - even with    
    
`lsof -R /dev/pts/0`
`
    COMMAND   PID  PPID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    bash    20451 20384 root    0u   CHR  136,1      0t0    4 /dev/pts/1
    bash    20451 20384 root    1u   CHR  136,1      0t0    4 /dev/pts/1
    bash    20451 20384 root    2u   CHR  136,1      0t0    4 /dev/pts/1
    bash    20451 20384 root  255u   CHR  136,1      0t0    4 /dev/pts/1`